# On closing the main Swing window, the other thread on the EventQueue gets not created

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, countdownlatch, eventqueue

I write Java SE 8 desktop application. It's got a Swing UI.

Platform:

- Eclipse IDE
- Windows 10 OS

Now when I close the main window, by pressing on the "X" on the top-right-corner, I have a listener to listen for such event.

The listener right here:

```
 private void listenerForClosingResources(){
         this.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
             @Override
             public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                 if(e.getID() == WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING){
                     CountDownLatch continueOn = new CountDownLatch(1);
                     saveUnsavedTmpProject(continueOn);

                     try {
                         continueOn.await();
                     }
                     catch(InterruptedException ee) {
                         ee.printStackTrace();
                     }                      
                 }
             }
         });    
     }
```

So, I use the listener to identify the window closing event, and when that happens I ask the user whether or not to save the project (it's data on DB).

This method (`saveUnsavedTmpProject(continueOn);`) leads to the other window which supposed to take the name under which to save the project.

Now the `CountDownLatch` forces the main window to stay up, up till when the user confirms/rejects saving the project on the other panel.

The other class method which creates the window, leading to saving the project, is right here:

```
public static void getInstance(CountDownLatch continueOn, String openProjectName) {
        if(frame == null) {
            synchronized(SaveAsPane.class) {
                if(frame == null) {
                    carryOn = continueOn;

                    if(!openProjectName.isEmpty()){
                        openProject = openProjectName;
                    }

                    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            try {
                                frame = new SaveAsPane();
                                frame.setVisible(true);
                                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(MainGUI.getMainGUI());

                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    });                     
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Now, when I run the app, I don't get inside the **run()** method (and no window pops-up). *But that only happens when I access this method only from the mentioned above listener.* Which has the `CountDownLatch`, and it appears that it stops the execution of the new thread.

The latch gets **counted-down** when the user confirms/denies saving the project, so that the execution flow continues on.
Yet, I create the additional thread on the `EventQueue`.

How come that the thread gets stopped?

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Based on you "example", it would be impossble for the second frame to take any input from the user (if it event displays its content) because you're blocking the EDT - A better, all round solution, would be to simply use a `JDialog`, which would do the same thing, but without blocking the EDT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **Java group** on `facebook.com` pointed me to the right direction.
The solution is this:

- redefine what the close button (X) does on the main GUI.

And here it comes:

```
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
```

And now when  I click the main GUI window's close button, the close does not lead to closing the window. Meaning that I don't need any longer the `CountDownLatch` class, which was stopping the main window from closing up (and waiting till the user **counts-down** on the other class).

In the end, I made the app to work in the way I like.